# Cannot use import statement outside a module when importing "uuid"

Tags: node.js

trying to import 'uuid' in the user model as
`import { v1 as uuidv1 } from "uuid";`

But, I don't know why it gives syntaxError like this
**import { v1 as uuidv1 } from "uuid";
^^^^^^SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module**

Comment: what version of node?

Comment: I have posted the answer different from one provided in the link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

-I am assuming that you have used export.modules in your uuid.js.

- Also i am assuming that uuid.js file is present in the same directory as the one in which your are importing the function.
- Now if you want to use the functions present in uuid.js to another file then you can use **require()** to import the function in your other js file. Try using below syntax to import the function.

  **const v1=require(./uuid);
  Now you can use v1.uuidv1(); in your js file.**
- However if you want to specifically use the syntax which you have used then you can **refer the link which have been provided by Daniel A White**

Comment: Thanks Daniel and Shikar,
I have changed import with  "var uuid = require('uuid');" and used like this "this.salt = uuid.v1();" and it worked.
Thanks again guys!